# how to remove duplicates if entire row has been duplicated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe have some duplicate rows. i want to remove only if entire row is duplicated.

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

i'm using above one but it removes everything if one column is duplicated.
like below

```
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
2   'cat'     'bat'   'lmn'
3   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'

**output**
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
```

i want output like this

```
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
2   'cat'     'bat'   'lmn'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.duplicated()` is working as intended. Your `df.loc` is filtering only for the duplicated ones instead of removing them. Instead of using `df.loc` you can simply index based on the Boolean series returned by `df.duplicated()` by inversing it with `~`

```
df[~df.duplicated()]
```

```
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
2   'cat'     'bat'   'lmn'
```

You could also directly use `df.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use drop_duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```